# How do I make an Android SeekBar?

Tags: java, android

I need an bar as like as image.
User can pull it and change value.

I need xml or java code for android studio.
[image: line bar]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a SeekBar
Here's a XML code

```
<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/simpleSeekBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Any opdates? I hope my answer helped you